# Registering Serviceworker in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, pushpad

I'm using pushpad (from pushpad.xyz) and followed the 3 initial steps to setup this SDK with my Laravel 5.5 Project.
But as soon as I visit a test view it just cannot find and register the Serviceworker.js
i tried placing it all over the place, almost in every folder now. So i know this is vaguely described but if you take a quick look at the Docs from pushpad you know what I mean.
Moreover, when i manually try to open it i get a 404.
also getting 404 when i try to import it via  from the https:// link where its located
when i copy its content and use it in a script tag i also get a 404.
im quite clueless as how to proceed

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
push-test:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a 
ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the 
script.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a **service-worker.js** file in the **root directory** of your website.

You can verify the installation by typing `https://example.com/service-worker.js` in your browser.